# coregister two images in fits format

Tags: image, matlab, alignment, fits

I have problem using `cpselect`to find control point selection for my images in fits format, this command cannot display the images with fits format. 
generally, I want to coregister two images in fit formats, so far I couldn't figure it out how to do it, however I knew how to use `imtransform`and 'cp2tform'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to read the images in first, and then give `cpselect` the names of the variables you stored the image in, rather than just the filenames of the images.

Try `fitsinfo(filename)` first and then `fitsread` - it may be as easy as something like:

```
image1 = fitsread('first.fits','image');
image2 = fitsread('second.fits','image');
cpselect(image1,image2);
```

But you need to check `fitsinfo` first to determine how to proceed in your specific case.

Comment: the images have read in fits format are appearing in cpselect completely black.

Comment: Might be because the combination of type (float, uint8, etc) and range of values in the image is not what `cpselect` expects. If `imshow(image1)` is black but `imshow(image1,[])` is not, it's a scaling issue.

Comment: yes, you are right. I have tried. As you said, for imshow(image) is black but when I used this imshow(image1,[]), it showed my image. Would you please help me how should I fixed it now?

Comment: If the values in your image are doubles, they need to be scaled to between 0 and 1.

Comment: I don't know how to do it, and I have to say I don't want to change the value of my pixels in my images since they are important for me and I want to extract them later